# The Borg and their use of time travel, particularly as a weapon

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, borg

In "First Contact" the Borg travel to the Earth's past to change history. Have the Borg ever made use of time travel as a weapon, much like (say) the Krenim in the Star Trek Voyage story "Year of Hell", or considered time travel to make assimilation easier.

Comment: related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/168089/in-star-trek-has-anyone-ever-weaponized-a-space-time-anomaly

Comment: Directly weaponizing time travel didn't work out too well for the Krenim.

Comment: Isn't one of the main reasons to assimilate a society to gain their technologies​. Iirc there are species which are left alone because they have nothing to offer the collective tech wise. Time traveling back to assimilate would mean missing out on lots of juicy tech stuff.

Comment: @WiggotheWookie - You're ignoring all of the advanced (but now extinct) species that the Borg could raid. I would imagine that assimilating an Iconian facility would be a very very very tempting prospect for the Borg

Comment: @WiggotheWookie But wasn't this the premise of the story First Contact?

Comment: @jim, I wondered about their logic in doing it. But maybe they saw the Federation as an existential threat and reasoned it was better to wipe them out before they existed even if it meant missing out on the technology.

Answer (score 7):

sounds cool - they should make a movie about that

**Star Trek: First Contact**

https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_First_Contact

> During an attack against Earth, the sensors detect that the Borg
>   sphere is creating a temporal vortex; the crew all watch the
>   viewscreen as the **Borg vessel disappears through the vortex and Earth
>   dramatically changes. Seeing that it is now populated entirely by Borg
>   drones and has a toxic atmosphere, they determine that history has
>   been changed**, having been protected from the changes themselves by the
>   wake of the temporal vortex. As the vortex collapses, Captain Picard
>   orders Lieutenant Hawk not to alter course and have the Enterprise
>   follow the Borg into the past – to repair whatever damage they've
>   done.

*(note: the film was released in 1996, and the Year of Hell in Voyager was broadcast in 1997)*

Comment: Not sure this qualifies as directly weaponizing time-travel. The time-travel is a tool, the Borg are still assaulting people with regular weapons. The Krenim weapon was directly removing someone from the timestream IIRC.

Comment: it's absolutely weaponizing - they effectively "kill" the Federation and Starfleet by going back in time and eliminating the opponent before it is even born - thus winning before the battle can even start

Comment: I'd count it as a tactic rather than a weapon.

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of the First Contact, I should have made that obvious and will amend the question.

Comment: @HarryJohnston so...you're looking for something like Deja Fu?